# Install options greyed out in Software Center

Tags: 11.10, software-center

I recently installed Oneiric, and I am unable to install any software through the software Center, because the *Install* option is greyed out for everything.

It loads all the software listings alright, but no install button.

I tried `apt-get update & apt-get upgrade`, enabled everything I saw fit in the software sources, yet no luck.

Installed Synaptic through command line, and it installs packages properly.
Since downloaded .deb packages open through the Software Center, I can't install them because install button is greyed out.

Any solutions?

Comment: A workaround for installing .deb files would be to run `sudo dpkg -i package.deb`.

Comment: I have the same problem on one computer. The `Install` button is always grey, even after trying the above the command line and a reboot.  The program says there is no network connection even though I post to this web site.

Comment: I have found `apt-get install {program}` works fine.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)